# The defining polynomials of complex abelian varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

By Chow's theorem, the complex abelian varieties should be algebraic. So, what is the defining polynomial? (It is easy when $g＝1$)

I  have searched it on arxiv and google scholar, but I get nothing. My teacher told me Mumford did this problem when he was young. Did he work out？

Comment: Yes. A complex  torus having a holomorphic embedding in projective space.

Comment: With complex abelian variety you mean a complex torus having an embedding in projective space ? Some keywords and refs are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_defining_abelian_varieties#General_case)

Comment: Thanks！！！！！！！！！